# window.onunload fires and then the user clicks stop

Tags: javascript

Here is the flow I am trying to figure out.

- User hits my page.
- User clicks a link and `onbeforeunload` and `unload` get fired. Here i am getting rid of href in some of my links.
- The page now hangs for a little bit giving the user a chance to hit the stop button in the browser.
- Since the page is still on the original page (not the new page that was requested and then stopped) the hrefs are still blank.

Is there any way of knowing if the user clicks a stop button and they are still on the same page?

The only way I can think off the top of my head is to put a setTimeout in the `onbeforeunload` or `unload` but I don't really like that because there are too many variables for it still being messed up.

Comment: Why are you doing this? To give the user a choice to not follow to the other page? You could provide your own "stop" button.

Comment: Im talking about the browser stop button and scenarios where just getting rid of the href will fail

Comment: Can you not capture the esc key or/and look for present url before removing the hrefs?

Comment: the Esc key would not happen if they press the stop button the the browser and I would need an interval to check on the href would I not?

Comment: Simple solution would be to do nothing in onunload, but i guess that's not an option. I don't really see the problem with the timeout solution, unless the page loading next is really slow to load. Another solution might be to add a invisible link covering the entire site. If the user clicks on it you can reinitialize the page (or do a page reload). Maybe you should make the link a transparent color (rgba(0,0,0, .3) or something)

Comment: Yeah I think the only way around this is putting the timeout there to check. Just didn;t like it because the new page is a somewhat slow load and depending on the connection speed it could be longer or shorter than the timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
window.unload = function(){
    var _href = $('selector').attr('href');
    $('selector').attr('href', '');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('selector').attr('href', _href);
    }, 1500);
}
```